# Flutter how to convery image in base64 string and show image again

Tags: flutter, dart

I am simply picking image from image_picker package like this

```
_imgFromCamera() async {
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50
);
final bytes = image.readAsBytesSync();

String base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);
print(base64Image);

setState(() {
  _image = image;
});
```

}

You can see I have convert image in the string also. I need to know how can I show this string as an image? Because I save this string on other page now I need to show is an image

Comment: Why do u need to convert the image into base64 string. Do you need to store it like that somewhere? Or is it just something you thought can help you?

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal I have updated the question I need to save this as a string because on another page I need to show the same image ill do it by sqllite so I think this is the easiest thing here to convert in the string.

Comment: If you do not need to store the image in a database, why don't you pass this file around and show an image using the file?

Comment: Need to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the base64 string into a file using

```
import `dart:covert`
Uint8List bytes = base64decode(_base64);
```

and then display it using the widget

```
Image.memory(bytes),
```

You can just write it in a single line but I split it for the sake of readability

```
Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String));
```